# How to programmatically turn on WiFi on Android device via react native?

Tags: react-native

How can I add an Enable WiFi button via React Native? (without modules)

**I find This for IOS:**

```
import { Platform, NativeModules } from 'react-native'

const IOSWifiManager = NativeModules.IOSWifiManager
```

But what is the best and easy way for android and what `permissions` needed.

[image: Photo]

Comment: Are you trying to add a button only? Should the button enable or disable WiFi?

Comment: I want to enable wifi or internet, I want to tell the user that he should turn the Internet on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**dulmandakh, Collaborator of react native said:**

> Sorry, RN does not have such feature. You might develop native module
>   for that.

[Ref Link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19990)

3rd-Party Module: [react-native-android-wifi](https://github.com/devstepbcn/react-native-android-wifi)